# Docker環境でのみnode.jsのaws-sdkでcognitoのユーザー情報取得ができない

Tags: javascript, aws, docker, node.js, docker-compose

#### 実現したいこと

AdminInitiateAuthCommandを使ってユーザー情報を取得したい

#### 前提

- ローカルでは動きますが、Dockerでは動きません。
- node.jsのバージョン: 18.13.0

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Could not load credentials from any providers
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```js
// main.ts
import {
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
  AdminInitiateAuthCommand,
  AdminInitiateAuthCommandInput,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider'
import { createHmac } from 'crypto'

const makeSecretHash = (username, client_id, client_secret) => {
  const secretHash = createHmac('sha256', client_secret)
    .update(`${username}${client_id}`)
    .digest('base64')

  return secretHash
}

const COGNITO_API_VERSION = '2016-04-18'
const COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID = process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
const COGNITO_CLIENT_ID = process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
const COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET
const AWS_REGION = process.env.AWS_REGION
const MY_USERNAME = process.env.MY_USERNAME
const MY_PASSWORD = process.env.MY_PASSWORD

const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
  apiVersion: COGNITO_API_VERSION,
  region: AWS_REGION,
})

/**
 * IDトークンを取得
 */
const getIdToken = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const params: AdminInitiateAuthCommandInput = {
    UserPoolId: COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId: COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
    AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: MY_USERNAME,
      PASSWORD: MY_PASSWORD,
      SECRET_HASH: makeSecretHash(
        MY_USERNAME,
        COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET
      ),
    },
  }
  const adminAuthCommand = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand(params)
  try {
    const data = await client.send(adminAuthCommand)
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.Session)
    // process data.
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(params)
    console.log(error.message)
  } finally {
    // finally.
  }
}

getIdToken()
```

docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3'

services:app:
    container_name: 'fuga-app'
    tty: true
    image: node:18.13.0-bullseye-slim
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3333:3333'
      - '5555:5555'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app:rw
    working_dir: /srv/app
    networks:
      - fuga-tier

networks:
  fuga-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

#### 試したこと

- Dockerのimage変更
- node.jsバージョンの変更

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/eau0l4fc4rxucg) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)